# How to use init method for multiple functions?

Tags: python, class, init

i tried to use multiple function in class using init method. following problem occur

```
class Person1:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hello", self.name)

    def age(self):
        print("age",self.age)

p = Person1('kashindra', 21)
p.say_hi()
p.age()
```

File "", line 16, in 
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Define `age` inside of class `Person1`

Comment: don't use the same name in Class for variable `self.age` and method `def age(self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class, you defined `age` as a variable, but you also defined it as a function. What you need to do is rename the function.

```
class Person1:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name

        self.age = age

    def say_hi(self):
            print("hello", self.name)

    def say_age(self):
        print("age", self.age)

p = Person1('kashindra', 21)
p.say_hi()
p.say_age()
```